# How to retrieve json object data made using Gson inside jquery ajax call made inside .jspf file to Js Array

Tags: jquery, gson

I have a ArrayList holding Hashmap objects as row details, where each HashMap is row put inside the ArrayList.i.e

```
ArrayList <HashMap> alData = new ArrayList <HashMap> ();
```

i have rows with in the ArrayList which i have converted to json object triggered via a jquery ajax call,the conversion is done using Gson as below.

```
Type listOfObject = new TypeToken< ArrayList <HashMap> >(){}.getType();
String sGson = new Gson().toJson(alData,listOfObject);
```

Please help me out in retrieve the data from the json object , at the client side with the jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST",   
    url: "/app1/servlet/Controller?handler=28&obid= " +  sbId  ,  
        data: "namedQuery=reports&queryParam=" + sbId, success: function (data) 
        { 
             Please help me retrieve the data from the 
             Gson object to convert to an Javascript array.
        },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
            },

       dataType: 'json' 
});
```

Thanks